# os.listdir doesn't work outside current directory

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import os

myPath = "/Users/myusername/"
listOfDirs = []

for d in os.listdir(myPath):
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        listOfDirs.append(d)
        
print(listOfDirs)
```

As long as the python file that contains the above is at the same location as `myPath` in above example, the `listOfDirs` will return a list of all the directories in `myPath`. If I change the `myPath` to a path different than where the script itself is (for example, `/Users/myusername/subdirectory/`, a directory I have permission for), I will end up with an empty list.

How do I get the os.listdir to work at any given path, even if it's different than the location of the script?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unable to reproduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list returned by `os.listdir(myPath)` is relative to `myPath` so you have to concatenate `myPath` and `d`:

```
for d in os.listdir(myPath):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(myPath, d)):
        listOfDirs.append(d)
```

You can use `pathlib` module as replacement:

```
import pathlib

listOfDirs = list(pathlib.Path(myPath).iterdir())
```

See the [correspondence between `pathlib` and `os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module)